# JQueryMobile Fading NavBar

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Does anyone know how to stop a fixed navbar from fading in and out every time I scroll. I'm using jquerymobile 1.0.1 with the following code but I can't stand how the nav bar fades in and out:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="footer-persist-a.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href="footer-persist-b.html">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="footer-persist-c.html">Emails</a></li>
            <li><a href="footer-persist-d.html">Emails</a></li>
            <li><a href="footer-persist-e.html">Emails</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

I don't just want the "toggle" fix. I would like it stay 100% visible 100% of the time. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Well for JQM 1.1 you actually set data-tap-toggle="false" on your footer.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
...
</div>
```

I like to do this to disable tapToggle in every page and also every fixed toolbar, header or footer:

```
$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
    $('[data-position=fixed]').fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle:false });
});
```

That way I don't have to keep typing data-tap-toggle="false" over and over.

Then if your using JQM 1.0.1 do:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageinit', function(){
    $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
});
```

Comment: This worked in the sense that the user can't click to toggle, but it still disappears when I scroll the page. I just want it to be completely visible all of the time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common grievance among JQM 1.0.x users. Their developers switched the  dynamicly positioned behavior you are referencing in their latest release. As of JQM 1.1 they use true fixed tool bars that do not fade. A stable version of JQM should be out shortly. Until then you could use version 1.1-rc1

There is one solution in older versions of JQM but this only works in ios 5:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `data-tap-toggle="true"` attribute to the `data-role="footer"` element to disable the tap-to-fade functionality:

> **tapToggle** *boolean*
>
> **default: true**
>
> Enable or disable the user's ability to toggle toolbar visibility with
> a tap on the screen (or a click, for mouse users). This option is also
> exposed as a data attribute: data-tap-toggle=""true""
>
> $("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: true }); Note: This
> behavior was formerly configurable as follows, but as of version 1.1
> this syntax is no longer supported:
>
> $.mobile.fixedToolbars    .setTouchToggleEnabled(false);

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html*

This should make your toolbar stay put all the time.

Comment: This worked in the sense that the user can't click to toggle, but it still disappears when I scroll the page. I just want it to be completely visible all of the time. Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile are you using?