# How to fix a header with jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQueryMobile. I have one problem regarding fixed headers. I have this code in my header div:

```
<div  data-role="header" hieght="100px" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"  style="min-height: 45px;">
    <h1>Nieuwspoort</h1>
</div>
```

In this div I have put data-position="fixed". The header is fixed but after I scroll the page my header is hidden and after I am done scrolling my header becomes visible again.

Comment: What version of Jquery Mobile are you using?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate check my aswer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829456/jquerymobile-fading-navbar

Comment: @cadaniel i am using jquery mobile version 1.7.1

Comment: Um thats your jquery version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper fixed header support has been introduced into jQueryMobile from version 1.1-rc1 onwards.

To fix your headers make sure to add the following attribute

```
data-position="fixed"
```

If you would like to disable tap-to-toggle then add the following

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

Your pastebin example modified to work:

```
<div  data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="a"  style="min-height: 45px;">
  <h1>Nieuwspoort</h1>
</div>
```

You need to ensure you are using 1.1-rc1 with jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: hi all i solved problem by finding iscroll jquery mobile library.

Comment: iscroll can present it's own issues, but if you are using a version of jquerymobile that is <1.1 then this is pretty much your only option.