# phonegap overscroll list

Tags: android, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an application on android(4.0.3) with phonegap

when I scroll down my list and reach the bottom, a blue highlight appears to indicate the end of scroll( not sure what its called, apparently overScroll).

I need to find a way to disable this or hide it because I have a fixed footer at the bottom and it overflows it. Any suggestions?

using following:

- Phonegap: 2.0.0
- android: 4.0.3
- jquery mobile: 1.1.0
- Device: Samsung galaxy S2

Picture of what overscroll:
http://i1075.photobucket.com/albums/w435/zhp_pilot/Rezound/ICICS/neomax_overscroll_glow.png

Comment: i think i had similar issue some times ago...may iscroll can solve ur problem check issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867677/how-to-fix-a-header-with-jquerymobile)

Comment: the footer/header doesn't go away, it just gets overlapped for a second with the overscroll. here is a picture showing overscroll http://i1075.photobucket.com/albums/w435/zhp_pilot/Rezound/ICICS/neomax_overscroll_glow.png

Comment: try to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` this meta tag to ur html header file and let me know if it is work

Comment: I have that included so its not the problem. I found a way to get it removed in normal android development (java and xml) using android:overScrollMode="never" on the scrollviews. But I just can't find a way to do that in phonegap.